# Chatting UI Design in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing a chatting application in IOS using Objective-c. Functionality wise every this ok, but i having some difficulty in design.

**Here is my output**
[image]

I created two cell identifiers to difference the type of message in side a table view.like this

[image]

And then i modify it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath. Like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableMainChatting.delegate = self;
    self.tableMainChatting.dataSource = self;
    self.navigationBarTitle.topItem.title = self.visitorName;
    self.tableMainChatting.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];



    // invoke visitor selected
    delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [delegate startChatting:self.visitorID VisitorName:self.visitorName VisitorTime:self.visitorStartTime];
    [delegate InvokeGetCurrentChattingHistory:self.visitorID];


}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    MessageItemObject *item = [messagesList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([item.Type isEqualToString:@"Visitor"]) {

        NSString *cellIdentifier = @"identify_visitor_chat";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableMainChatting dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }

        UILabel *visitorMessage = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5030];
        visitorMessage.text = item.Messagetext;
        visitorMessage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        visitorMessage.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;



        visitorMessage.frame =CGRectMake(visitorMessage.frame.origin.x, visitorMessage.frame.origin.y, 250, 60);
        visitorMessage.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"RobotoSlab-Bold" size:10];
        visitorMessage.numberOfLines=0;
        visitorMessage.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

        [visitorMessage sizeToFit];



        UILabel *messageTime = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5031];
        messageTime.text = item.MessageTime;
        return cell;



    } else {
        NSString *cellIdentifier = @"identify_operator_chat";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableMainChatting dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }

        UILabel *visitorMessage = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5032];
        visitorMessage.text = item.Messagetext;
        visitorMessage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        visitorMessage.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;


        UILabel *messageTime = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5033];
        messageTime.text = item.MessageTime;

        return cell;
    }

}
```

I want to remove all the separating lines and also i want to set the label hight depending on its text.

Comment: Use this method.
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: @SathyaBaman...I'm also facing same kind of issue...Please update a working sample code...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to set UITableViewCell heightForRowAtIndexPath to **UITableViewAutomaticDimension**.

Use the following methods:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 100; //Any default size of the cell
}
```

Also you have to set AutoLayout for those chat UILabel which is important. Please follow the autolayout instructions from [here](http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/).

Comment: hy tnx. but still there is a line separator inside the cell identifier

Comment: Write `tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;` in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Also please approve or upvote if this answer helped you.

Answer (score 0):

If you target for devices before iOS 8.0, you can calculate your dynamic cell height by using this function

```
-(CGFloat)getLabelHeightFor:(NSString*)text font:(UIFont*)font width:(CGFloat)width {
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    lbl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 0);
    lbl.numberOfLines = 0;
    lbl.font = font;
    lbl.text = text;
    [lbl sizeToFit];

    return lbl.frame.size.height;
}
```

And in your controller

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CGFloat height = [self getLabelHeightFor:MESSAGE font:YOUR_FONT width:LABEL_WIDTH];
    return height;
}
```